# Pesquisa no SqlServer com Query

Tags: delphi

Estou com o seguinte problema:
Gostaria que a pessoa digitasse o numero de ribbons em um edit e esses valor fosse comparado com os valores no banco de dados e quando forem iguais. apresentar eles no relatorio:

```
SQL.add('Select * from "controle" where "ribbons" = :ribbons');
FrMRelatorio.ADOQuery1.Parameters.ParamByName('ribbons').Value := edit1.Text;
```

Com o seguinte codigo o mesmo sempre retorna os ribbons referente a 4
aonde posso estar errando?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode também ao invés de criar parâmetros adicionar o edit1.text dentro do SQL, dessa forma:

```
SQL.Add('Select * from controle where ribbons = '+QuotedStr(edit1.text.Text)+'');
```

Comment: Funcionou exatamente como eu queria.

Answer (score 1):

Você deve remover as aspas dupla (**""**) da tabela `controle` e do campo `ribbons` e também especificar o parâmetro para query que você esta usando.

Ficaria assim:

```
FrMRelatorio.ADOQuery1.SQL.add('Select * from controle where ribbons = :ribbons');
FrMRelatorio.ADOQuery1.Parameters.ParamByName('ribbons').Value := edit1.Text;
```

Veja mais sobre [como trabalhar com parâmetros na query](http://www.andrecelestino.com/delphi-trabalhando-com-parametros-na-query/).

Answer (score 0):

Quando você utiliza parâmetros, você precisa definir os mesmos na propriedade “Parameters” mais quando você precisar fazer alguma mudança é precisar, por exemplo, carregar os campos da sua tabela você pode ter problemas é precisar redefinir tudo novamente da mesma forma que se você precisar definir mascara de campos você deve usar o evento Before Open. Geralmente eu utilizo  (ADOQuery + DataSetProvider + ClientDataSet). Não utilizo parâmetros, faço as consultas usando sql puro.

Você pode montar até uma procedure para que possa fazer todas as suas consultas, geralmente eu crio uma ADOQuery apenas para consultas da seguinte forma: (sqlGenerico + dspGenerico + cdsGenerico);

```html
    //adicionar no type
    procedure ConsultaDadosGenerico(NomeDoClienteDataSet:TClientDataSet; sqlConsulta :String);
```

```html
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ConsultaDadosGenerico(cdsCliente, 'Select * from controle where ribbons = ' +  QuotedStr(Trim(Edit1.Text)) );
end;

procedure TForm1.ConsultaDadosGenerico(NomeDoClienteDataSet: TClientDataSet; sqlConsulta :String);
begin
  NomeDoClienteDataSet.Close;
  NomeDoClienteDataSet.CommandText := '';
  NomeDoClienteDataSet.CommandText := sqlConsulta;
  NomeDoClienteDataSet.Open;
end;
```